# Including banner created with Google Web Designer in a page

Tags: html, google-web-designer

I've created an HTML5 based banner with Google Web Designer. When published it saves as an HTML file. My question is: how do I put this HTML ad on my site? Should I include the HTML file in some way?

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to include your creation to a website.

1. Include all assets(multimedia) and HTML in the page with the required js/css that was exported from GWD.
2. Upload the whole folder on your server and serve it as an iframe.
3. Get a <strike>DoubleClick</strike> Google Ad Manager account and upload your creation there. Then include the code generated by <strike>DoubleClick</strike> Google Ad Manager in your website. Best method in my opinion.(faster loading times, no extra server loading, easy tracking of ads)

Comment: @Emil It does not seem really helpful though. Documentation about using your creation lacks.

Comment: After searching fro many Solutions , This was the Perfect Answer

Answer (score -3):

I found [this example on w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp):

```
<object width="1000" height="300" data="gwd_preview_myBanner/index.html"></object>
```

where `gwd_preview_myBanner/index.html` is a relative path to the banner itself - the HTML file produced by Google Web Designer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13230624)

Comment: ah - I edited this an the line of code seems to have vanished... Sorry my first time answering...edited (I hope)